# making model work better for tfmobile/tflite

Tags: tensorflow, training-data, object-detection-api, tensorflow-lite

So I have trained an object detection model with tensorflow.

I retrained the model (ssd_mobilenet_v2) using a data set containing traffic sign with an image size of 1920x1080 each. The trained model worked really well when ran on desktop.

Now when I ran it on mobile using tfMobile, the Model performed poorly. One thing that stood out to me is that the input for the mobile prediction is reduced to 300x300.

How big of an impact is this? Would retraining the model on images with the same size or aspect ratio improve the model accuracy on mobile?

I also feel like my model is way slower than the one provided from the android demo.

Comment: The input is likely also reduced on desktop, even if you don't do it yourself, the  model is trained with a specific image size which is configured in the pipeline conf. What exactly do you mean by "it perfed poorly"? do you have numbers or just gut feeling? maybe the images of your dataset are just not very representative of your phone's camera pictures?

Comment: The impact of the size btw is studied (I think) in the mobilenet paper, and in various places across the web, and indeed higher resolution leads to slightly better results but at the cost of inference time.

Comment: and for the speed, maybe the original model was quantized and yours isn't?

Comment: The model that I used is the one obtainable from the model-zoo. Is it necessary to re-quantize a retrained model? I will try to retrain the model with pictures from the phones camera. Thank you for your advice.